# Error in production "Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: ..." inmy react routes (Breeze-react-laravel10-inertia)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, routes, breeze, inertiajs

On my local server, using npm run dev, I can see the react routes without a problem. But on my production server, when I want to access the routes, this problem appears.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9DTJ.png)

My vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.jsx',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),
    ],
});
```

My app.jsx file
`createInertiaApp({ title: (title) =>` ${title} - ${appName}`, resolve: async (name) => resolvePageComponent(` ./pages/${name}.jsx`,
import.meta.glob("./pages/**/*.jsx")
),setup({ el, App, props }) {
const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

```
        let selectedLayout;
        // Ejemplo de condición para seleccionar el layout basado en la ruta
        if (currentPath.startsWith("/constructor") || currentPath.startsWith("/comentarios")) {
            selectedLayout = <ConstructorLayout>{/* Puedes añadir props específicas aquí */}</ConstructorLayout>;
            createRoot(el).render(
                React.cloneElement(selectedLayout, null, <App {...props} />)
            );
        }else{
            
            createRoot(el).render(
                
                    <App {...props} />
                
            );
        }

       
    },`
```

Comment: Did you run `npm run build` ?